# Can't get expression working against grep or findstr

Tags: regex, grep

I can get my regex working [here](https://regex101.com/r/sB2lP5/1), but can't get it working in grep or findstr

Tried using it straight:

```
findstr /r "(232323)(\d*)(1313)" *
grep "(232323)(\d*)(1313)" *
```

Comment: Can you use `Perl` `-P` option with your version of grep?

Comment: With plain grep: `grep 232323[[:digit:]]*1313 *` -- capturing parentheses are `\(` and `\)`, but you don't need parentheses here.

Comment: thanks everyone, but anything for findstr?, I work with Win servers unfortunately, I use grep on my local system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -P "(232323)(\d*)(1313)" *
```

You can use it with `perl` mode.